# Play Framework Netty Error with Expect 100 Continue

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a client that I don't control that **POST** a  **JSON** with header `Expect: 100-continue` to a Play Server 2.1.2. The content of the Post is actually very short and contains the data I'm interested in.

I keep getting these errors in the console:

```
[error] play - Oops, unexpected message received in NettyServer (please report this problem): org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpChunk@52ed100b   
[error] play - Oops, unexpected message received in NettyServer (please report this problem): org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpChunk$1@6acd73be    
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

My controller consists of a very simple method:

```
object TestController extends Controller {

    def foo = Action {
        Ok("bar")
    }
}
```

I'm using the head of 2.1.x branch of Play (July 19th). Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is linked [to a race condition in the framework code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/PgFfqkT0Zgg/xq31rj_1hwoJ).

The [issue has been fixed](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/1346) on master and will be included in [2.1.3 release](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues?milestone=5&page=1&state=closed).